# Замена элемента списка с последним

Tags: python, list, индексы

Дано задание следующего типа: Задать в программе список X, состоящий из 10 целых чисел. Найти максимальный из отрицательных элементов списка и поменять его местами с последним.
Максимально отрицательное я нашел, а вот как сделать так, чтобы это число(максимально отрицательное) менялось местами с последним?

```
import random

s = []
maxot = -10**10

for i in range(10):
    s.append(int(input('Введите любое число: \n')))
    if s[i] < 0 and s[i] > maxot:
        maxot = s[i]
print(s)
print('Максимально отрицательное число: \n')
print(maxot)
```

Comment: вам нужен индекс этого максимально отрицательного, а индекс последнего - s[-1], и потом: a, b = b, a

Comment: спасибо за отзыв. В данном случае получается s[maxot],s[-1]=s[-1],s[maxot]? Не могу понять как обозначить в коде, чтобы программа находила индекс максимально отрицательного элемента, он же может быть любым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменять местами элементы в списке можно зная их индексы.
Последний элемент имеет индекс -1, а max_negative_index сохраните в цикле рядом с maxot:

```
# import random

s = []
# maxot = -10**10
maxot = float('-inf')
max_negative_index = 0

for i in range(10):
    s.append(int(input('Введите любое числа: \n')))
    # if s[i] < 0 and s[i] > maxot:
    if maxot < s[i] < 0:
        maxot = s[i]
        max_negative_index = i

print(s)
print('Максимально отрицательное число: \n')
print(maxot)

# меняем местами последний элемент с наибольшим из отрицательных элементов
s[-1], s[max_negative_index] = s[max_negative_index], s[-1]
print(s)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -7, 8, -9, 42, 13]
Максимально отрицательное число: 
-2
[1, 13, 3, -4, 5, -7, 8, -9, 42, -2]
```

PS `maxot = float('-inf')` лучше, чем `maxot = -10**10`; и`if maxot < s[i] < 0` нагляднее, чем `if s[i] < 0 and s[i] > maxot` ;)

Comment: Все коротко и ясно, благодарю. А за отдельную функцию (float('-inf')) огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Ibragim дерзайте! есть что улучшать: if maxot < s[i] < 0 например ;) и `max_negative` понятнее, чем `maxot` имхо